# Can this group be written as a semidirect product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, semidirect-product

Assume, $\mathbb{F}$ is a field of $char=0$ and $\mathbb{F}^\ast$ be the group of non-zero scalars. Let $G=\{(c,A)\in \mathbb{F}^\ast \times GL_n(\mathbb{F}) | AA^t=cI_{n\times n} \}$. Then $G$ is a group with the obvious entry wise multiplicaton. Can we write $G$ as a suitable semidirect product? If not in general, can we do this for the complex numbers in particular? For the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ it seems $G$ can be written as $\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \ltimes O_n$, as follows from the following split exact sequence: $1\to O_n \xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \to 1 $, here $i$ is $A \mapsto (1, A)$ and $p$ is $(c, A) \mapsto c$. A splitting map $s: \mathbb{R}_{> 0}\to G$ can be given by $s(c):= (c, \sqrt cI)$. So the question is whether we can write the above defined $G$ as a suitable semidirect product in more general situations, and if not why?

Comment: In general, the projection $p$ will be onto $(\mathbb F^*)^2$. It splits if and only if the square map $\mathbb F^* \rightarrow (\mathbb F^*)^2$ does, as a group morphism (that is, iff there is a product-preserving square root function for $\mathbb F$). Such a map exists for subfields of $\mathbb R$, but I do not know (at least at first thought) for which fields it exists in general.  (I would guess not for $\mathbb C$ ? What about finite fields ?)

Comment: This is not obvious to me. How do you prove that if $A A^t = c I_n$ for some $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb F)$, then $c$ is a square in $\mathbb F$ ?

Comment: $\det(A) = \det(A^t) = \sqrt{c}$.

Comment: I think for finite fields of order $q$, the squaring map on the field will split if and only if either $q$ is even (when all elements have a unique square root) or $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.